# Can i use both DNS service for my domain name Godaddy and Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, godaddy-api

What if I'm using Godaddy for Domain hosting and DNS management for our company website, but I want to use subdomains for services we've developed on AWS?

For example:
website.com is hosted and DNS managed on GoDaddy.
administrator.website.com is where we have the administration portion of our SaaS solution.
I have a Route53 hosted zone for administrator.website.com in AWS.

1. When I add the four administrator.pressurepro.us NS records into GoDaddy's Nameservers section, should I re-add the original 2 NameServers used by GoDaddy for website.com as well?
2. Will a visitor to website.com still get directed to our company website with all the DNS records in Godaddy managing the traffic?
3. Will a visitor to adminstrator.website.com go through AWS Route 53 (configured to point towards our EC2/Beanstalk)?
4. My SES domain and DKIM verification records for adminstration.website.com need to reside in Route53, correct?

Comment: I believe your question 1 you want to refer to administrator.website.com. If so, you should edit your question to avoid data exposure.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: I am not sure about GoDaddy, but if you want to delegate administrator sub-domain to route53, you just need to use the 4 NS values from your Route53 hosted zone.

Q2: Yes, everything not related to administrator.website.com will be handled by GoDaddy DNS.

Q3: Yes, everything related to administrator.website.com will be handled by Route53.

Q4: Yes, as it is managed by Route53.